# How to exclude special characters from a Textfield in React Hooks Form 7.0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

```
 <Controller
              control={control}
              name="txnId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <MuiTextField
                  type="text"
                  required
                  id="txnId"
                  label="Payment Ref. No."
                  variant="outlined"
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                  {...field}
                />
              )}
            />
```

> My useForm looks like this where I am setting the txnId. MuiTextField is the Material UI Textfields here

```
const { control, setValue, getValues} = useFormContext();
const methods = useForm({
defaultValues: {
  txnId:""
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe it's be better to use controlled input instead od uncontrolled one like below:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
txnId:""
});
```

and then use onchange to set value

```
const onChange = (e)=>{
const {value,name}=e.target;
//some logic to exclue char before setting in state
setState(s=>({...s,txnId:vakue});
}
 <Controller
              control={control}
              name="txnId"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <MuiTextField
                  type="text"
                  required
                  id="txnId"
                  label="Payment Ref. No."
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.txnId}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                  {...field}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Comment: txnId state is not changing if I type in the textfield

Comment: the onChange method is not getting triggered

Comment: humm, i didn't used control comp before, do you need to use it, without it you can have everything needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
  const blockInvalidChars = (event) => {
    const regex = /[\\/[\]:¦<>+=;,*?"]/;
    const { key } = event;
    if (regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

<MuiTextField
  type="text"
  required
  id="txnId"
  label="Payment Ref. No."
  variant="outlined"
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
  onKeyPress={blockInvalidChars}
  {...field}
/>
```